# Checkstyle generate incompleted XML report

Tags: checkstyle

I run Checkstyle with Ant. Some projects work correctly, however, there's one project with very strange result. The XML report is not completed, no end tag and in the last line, the full path of JAVA file is not commpleted.

I copy some lines to here, after hide some sensitive information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<checkstyle version="8.43">
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\src\com\a\b\c\d\e\f\v1_0\identification\impl\AServiceAdapterImpl.java">
</file>
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\src\com\a\b\c\d\e\f\v1_0\identification\impl\sdo1.java">
</file>
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\src\com\a\b\c\d\e\f\v1_0\identification\impl\dto2.java">
</file>
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\src\com\a\b\c\d\e\f\v1_0\identification\impl\sdo3.java">
</file>
```

.....

And these last line of file:

```
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\test\com\a\b\x\y\z\international\converter\convert1.java">
</file>
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\test\com\a\b\x\y\z\international\converter\XConverterTest.java">
</file>
<file name="D:\projects\service-impl\test\com\a\b\x\y\z\international\con
```

No end tag, the last line is not completed.
And no thing show ion console.
How can I fix it

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the new Checkstyle version don't support UTF8 method name/field name. After rename those variable, it works!